# Elementor form data to ACF

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, database

I've developed a webpage incorporating the Elementor Pro form widget to enable users to submit a listing on my website. [enter link description here](https://thenationpost.ca/add-business/)

I have utilized the ACF plugin to create all the necessary backend fields, ensuring their names match accordingly. However, when submitting the form, the resulting post appears as "Untitled," with all fields empty. I would greatly appreciate any assistance in resolving this issue.

```
    // Process business form submission
add_action('elementor_pro/forms/new_record', 'save_business_data', 10, 2);
function save_business_data($record, $handler) {
    $form_data = $record->get_formatted_data();

    // Check if the form belongs to the specific form ID
    if ($record->get_form_settings('form_id') === 'business_submition') {
        $post_data = array(
            'post_type' => 'business',
            'post_status' => 'publish',
            'post_title' => sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['business_name']['value']),
            'post_content' => sanitize_textarea_field($form_data['form_fields']['business_description']['value']),
            'post_name' => sanitize_title($form_data['form_fields']['post_slug']['value']),
            'post_author' => get_current_user_id()
        );

        // Insert the post
        $post_id = wp_insert_post($post_data);

        // Set the post thumbnail
        if (!empty($form_data['form_fields']['business_image']['value'])) {
            set_post_thumbnail($post_id, $form_data['form_fields']['business_image']['value']);
        }

        // Save ACF fields
        update_field('business_description', sanitize_textarea_field($form_data['form_fields']['business_description']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('email_address', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['email_address']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('phone_number', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['phone_number']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('website_address', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['website_address']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('facebook', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['facebook']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('linkedin', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['linkedin']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('twitter', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['twitter']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('instagram', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['instagram']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('custom_link', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['custom_link']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('custom_link_title', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['custom_link_title']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('youtube_link', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['youtube_link']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('video_link', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['video_link']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('opening_hours', sanitize_textarea_field($form_data['form_fields']['opening_hours']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('services', sanitize_textarea_field($form_data['form_fields']['services']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('location', array(
            'address' => sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['location_latitude']['value']),
            'lat' => sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['location_latitude']['value']),
            'lng' => sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['location_longitude']['value']),
        ), $post_id);
        update_field('get_direction', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['get_direction']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('business_city', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['business_city']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('on_map_description_-_max_150_characters', sanitize_text_field($form_data['form_fields']['on_map_description_-_max_150_characters']['value']), $post_id);
        update_field('add_b_logo', $form_data['form_fields']['add_b_logo']['value'], $post_id); // Add Logo field
    }
}
```